# HTML Element over Full Screen Flash Movie

Tags: html, fullscreen, flash, brightcove

I have a flash movie player (from brightcove). When it plays a movie in full screen, I want to be able to overlay HTML5 elements on top of the video. The elements will display closed captions rendered using javascript.

NOTE: I avoid putting captions into the flash movie itself because Brightcove does not allow you to style the captions.  I can't change the typography, fontsize, colours etc...  So I want to overlay the captions in html 5, css 3 and javascript.  It works great when the movie player is embeded on a page using `<param name="wmode" value="transparent">`, but I haven't figured out how to achieve the same effect in full screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this isn't possible because once you got to full screen your no longer in the browser at all, only in the flash player. The reason it works with the value="transparent" embed is because your still in browser at that point. Once you go full screen, everything is being handled by the player.